# Bilinear Transform vs Standard Numerical Methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, control-theory, linear-control, approximate-integration

I am not very familiar with control theory but have a decent bit of experience with classical numerical integration.

I am looking at a the equation

$$\dot{x}(t) = Ax(t) + Bu(t) \hspace{1cm} x(0) =0 $$
(coming from a state-space model) and the way that I would handle this is by multiplying by the matrix exponential and integrating to get:

$$x(t) = \int_0^t e^{A(t - \tau)}Bu(\tau) \,d\tau$$

and then handling the convolution integral on the right hand side using some standard quadrature. And if I wanted to convert this continuous system to a discrete one I would use something like:

$$x(t + h) = x(t) + \int_t^{t + h} e^{A(t + h - \tau)} Bu(\tau) \,d\tau$$

with a quadrature rule for the integral on the RHS (which is of course just the quadrature rule of the full interval applied to a uniform partition.)

However, the authors of a paper I'm looking at use the bilinear transform from control theory.

My understanding of the bilinear transform is that it computes the transfer function of a discrete system coming from the trapezoid rule and the transfer function of the continuous system coming from the continuous integral and equates them to give a transformation to apply in "Laplace transform space" to go from continuous to discrete time. Is this correct?

Now, If I take the bilinear transform as a given and apply a Laplace transform to the above system, I understand that after a bit of algebra I will arrive at the discrete Laplace transform (or z-transform?) of the discrete system:
$$x(t + h) = (I - h/2 A)^{-1}(I + h/2 A)x(t) + h(I - h/2 A)^{-1}Bu(t)$$

which I am not sure how to derive from the original system using a traditional numerical method (I tried just applying trapezoid rule + pade approximation but don't see immediately how to get the $$h(I - h/2 A)^{-1}B$$ portion).

My questions are:

How does this compare to other numerical methods? I can compute the order numerically so I'm not so concerned about that, but why would one take the approach of using the bilinear transfer function over the type of numerical integral/differential equation solve that I outlined initially?

Answer (score 1):

The main reasons why we use (forward/backward) Euler or bilinear transformations is that they allow us to obtain an explicit form for the discretized model associated with a continuous-time system.

In control, the input is usually not known beforehand and must be computed based on the model of the system and the different control objectives. In this regard, it is not really possible to use numerical integration methods, as you first mentioned.

It could be possible to assume that the input is constant over each component of the partitions and obtain a model this way. In such a case, though, we have an explicit solution for a system whose input is piecewise constant and is given by

$$\displaystyle x(t+h)=e^{Ah}x(t)+\left(\int_0^he^{A(h-s)}Bds\right) u_t$$ where $u(t+s)=u_t$ for all $s\in[0,h)$.

Regarding the bilinear transform, it is enough to note that

$$x(t+h)-x(t)=\int_0^h(Ax(t+s)+Bu(t+s))ds.$$

The trapezoidal rule says that

$$\int_0^hf(s)ds\approx \dfrac{h}{2}(f(0)+f(h)),$$
which yields

$$\int_0^hAx(t+s)+Bu(t+s))ds\approx \dfrac{h}{2}(Ax(t)+Bu(t)+Ax(t+h)+Bu(t+h)).$$

Now define the shift operator $\sigma$ as $\sigma u(t)=u(t+h)$, which yields
$$\dfrac{h}{2}(Ax(t)+Bu(t)+Ax(t+h)+Bu(t+h))\approx \dfrac{h}{2}(\sigma+1)(Ax(t)+Bu(t))$$

Therefore,

$$(\sigma -1)x(t)\approx\dfrac{h}{2}(\sigma+1)(Ax(t)+Bu(t))$$

and thus

$$\dfrac{h}{2}\dfrac{\sigma-1}{\sigma+1}x(t)\approx Ax(t)+Bu(t).$$

This shows that the derivative operator (i.e. $s$) can be approximated by the operator $\dfrac{h}{2}\dfrac{\sigma-1}{\sigma+1}$

Comment: Could I ask for a bit of further help? In particular, you have using the trapezoid rule
$$(I - \frac{h}{2} A)x(t + h) = (I + \frac{h}{2} A) + \frac{h}{2}B u(t) + \frac{h}{2}Bu(t + h)$$
which is not the same as the approximation that I've written above. Unless you assume the u(t) term is constant over h or consider the u(t) terms as a trapezoidal approximation of an integral themselves and replace that integral with a rectangular approximation.

Comment: Also, if we look at the integral version
$$x(t + h) = e^{Ah}x(t) + \left(\int_0^h e^{A(h - s)} B \,ds\right) u(t)$$
then the matrix in front of x(t) is the (1,1)-pade approx which is fine, but I can't find a reasonable approximation of that integral which gives the same matrix that I wrote in the discrete update above. The closest I managed was to use the rectangular approximation
$$\int_0^h e^{A(h - s)}B \,ds \approx he^{Ah}B$$
and then use the terrible (0,1)-pade approximation to the matrix exponential:
$$e^{Ah} \approx \left(I - \frac{h}{2}A\right)^{-1}$$

Comment: One question at a time. In your post, there are a series of misconceptions which may it difficult to follow. For instance, the last but one equation is not a transform. Also, you mention the use of a transformation, but you fail to provide a source for that and what you wrote comes out of nowhere. So, either you will need to provide a source or you will have to provide all the calculations.

Comment: For the second you can try to write $e^{Ah}=e^{Ah/2}(e^{-Ah/2})^{-1}\approx(I+Ah/2)(I-Ah/2)^{-1}$.

Comment: I am following roughly https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/050643416 (2209-2210) to understand https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.13985.pdf (page 4). A similar but not identical derivation using transfer functions https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/45042/bilinear-transformation-of-continuous-time-state-space-system

I agree with that approximation to the matrix exponential, that is what I would normally do. I am trying just trying to derive the $$(I - h/2 A)^{-1}Bu(t)$$ term without relying on the transfer function

Comment: Also the update
$$x(t + h) = x(t) + \int_t^{t + h} e^{A(t + h - \tau)}Bu(\tau) \,d\tau$$
which I wrote initially is clearly wrong. Apologies for that!

Comment: I mean you just do the math and change the derivative operator $s$ by $2(z+1)/(h(z-1)$, do the algebra and consider that $u(t)$ is constant, so $(z+1)u(t)=2u(t)$ and this is done.